# Can I replace form element loop parsing with newer Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))?

Tags: javascript, forms

Can I safely replace this

```
document.getElementById("frm-Main").addEventListener("submit", (e) =>
{        
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // const frmMain = e.target;
    const frmMain = document.querySelector('#frm-Main');

    let params = [];

    const inputs = frmMain.getElementsByTagName("input");
    console.log(inputs);

    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio' && inputs[i].checked != true) continue;
        if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked != true) continue;

        params.push({ id: inputs[i].name, value: inputs[i].value });
    }

    const selects = frmMain.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++)
    {            
        params.push({ id: selects[i].name, value: selects[i].value });
    }    

    fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));    
});
```

with this ?

```
document.getElementById("frm-Main").addEventListener("submit", (e) =>
{        
    e.preventDefault();

    const frmMain = document.querySelector('#frm-Main');    
    const formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(frmMain));

    fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
});
```

Comment: Did you try and what happened? Also why?

Comment: ```console.log()``` both method's final data and see... if you get the same JSON structure I don't see as to why not to replace it.

Comment: I have a very large form. The output 'looks' the same. But will there be any inconsistencies in different versions of different browsers ? (I know this is not supported in IE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, yes, but it is not generically safe. It will depend on whether the formdata includes entries with duplicate names. Multiselect for example may, as could checkbox groups. You may also run into problems in Safari related to variations in the radiogroup API.

Also, FormData values could be files. You may need to perform additional custom serialization to convert those values to a JSON representation.

The following interactive demo shows how using `Object.fromEntries` will not work correctly (without some additional prior transformation) in scenarios where the formdata includes members with common names. It also shows the output with as it would appear in the body of an HTTP request if sent as multipart or urlencoded formdata rather than a JSON representation.

```js
let controller;

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  update();
});

form.addEventListener('change', update);

update();

function renderEntry([ key, value ]) {
  return `[ ${ JSON.stringify(key) }, ${ JSON.stringify(value) } ]`
}

async function update() {
  controller?.abort();

  let { signal } = controller = new AbortController;
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let object = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  let rawUSP = await new Response(new URLSearchParams(formData)).text();
  let rawFD = await new Response(formData).text();

  if (!signal.aborted) {
    outputEntries.innerText = Array.from(formData, renderEntry).join('\n');
    outputFromEntries.innerText = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
    outputRawUSP.innerText = rawUSP;
    outputRawFD.innerText = rawFD;
  }
}
```

```css
code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1ch;
  white-space: pre;
}

dd, dl, dt {
  all: unset;
  display: block;
}

dt {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 1ch;
}

.fields {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.field:last-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

output {
  background: azure;
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="foo">Foo</label>
    <select multiple id="foo" name="foo">
      <option selected>bar</option>
      <option selected>baz</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="qux">Qux</label>
    <input id="qux" name="qux" value="quux">
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Corge</legend>
    <div class="fields">
      <input checked id="grault" name="corge" type="checkbox" value="grault">
      <label for="grault">grault</label>
      <input id="garply" name="corge" type="checkbox" value="garply">
      <label for="garply">garply</label>
      <input checked id="waldo" name="corge" type="checkbox" value="waldo">
      <label for="waldo">waldo</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="output">Output</label>
    <output id="output">
      <dl>
        <dt>FormData entries</dt>
        <dd><code id="outputEntries"></code></dd>
        <dt>Object.fromEntries</dt>
        <dd><code id="outputFromEntries"></code></dd>
        <dt>FormData application/x-www-form-urlencoded body</dt>
        <dd><code id="outputRawUSP"></code></dd>
        <dt>FormData multipart/form-data body</dt>
        <dd><code id="outputRawFD"></code></dd>
      </dl>
    </output>
  </div>
</form>
```

The reason the `Object.fromEntries` result is missing “bar” and “grault” (in the form’s initial state) is that as the entries are consumed, each time the same name is encountered in an entry, it will result in overwriting the previous property. An object can only have one own-property with a given key.

This doesn’t mean you should never use it for quick form-to-object mapping. If you’re working with a simple form where all the fields are known to be singular text values, it would be fine. But you’ll probably want a more robust solution to avoid creating a hazard later in case someone adds new fields that do need to map to other representations in JSON.

If creating a more robust mapping function, `Object.fromEntries` is still potentially useful. You’d just need to perform the mapping from the form to its “json entries” first (think `Object.fromEntries(getFormEntries(form))`). The `FormData` type doesn’t just not model arrays in a way that makes sense for JSON — it also doesn’t know about other JSON types like Number and Boolean.

That `getFormEntries` function in the middle might be written as a generator function that yields `[ name, value ]` pairs. When deriving the values, you might look at the types of the form controls themselves to determine how to represent their values in JSON. For example, `element.type === 'select-multiple'` tells you to base the JSON value on `element.selectedOptions`, while `element.type === 'number'` or `element.type === 'range'` suggests you’d want `element.valueAsNumber` instead of `element.value`.

```
// Pseudo code! — a real implementation would need to account
// for RadioNodeList/its children, deciding whether checkboxes
// are booleans, string-valued, or arrays, and lots of other
// things — but the gist is something like this:

function formToJSON(form) {
  return Object.fromEntries(getFormEntries(form));
}

function * getFormEntries(form) {
  for (let control of form.elements) {
    if (!control.disabled) {
      yield [ control.name, getFormControlValue(control) ];
    }
  }
}

function getFormControlValue(control) {
  switch (control.type) {
    case 'number':
      return control.valueAsNumber;
    case 'select-multiple':
      return Array.from(control.selectedOptions, option => option.value);
    /* ... */
    default:
      return control.value;
  }
}
```

You would also want to exclude items which are `disabled`. Looking at the [`FormData` construction algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) could provide clues here, since you’d probably want to replicate its rules for deciding which form controls model submittable values — the twist is just that you want to derive representations of those values differently.

Note that there’s no right answer for mapping form values to JSON. For example, how should we represent the value of an `<input type="date">`? We might want to use `element.value` (`"2021-02-09"`), but maybe we’d prefer to represent it with `element.valueAsDate.toISOString()` (`"2021-02-09T00:00:00.000Z"`). The answer would depend on your specific needs and the contracts you’re developing.

Comment: Shouldn't foo be foo[] ?

Comment: That is just a naming convention. Some systems use it to overlay semantics on formdata for interpretation, but it isn't part of the media type itself. The result would be the same either way - the duplicate key would get overwritten when using fromEntries.

Comment: Somehow I thought foo could be sent as an array to the server using formData.

Comment: FormData can be, but it's not exactly "an array" - it's just that the same field name can appear more than once. Naming rules like "end with []" give the server a clue to treat the single-entry case as an array even if it doesn't have express knowledge of the form contract.

Comment: @anjanesh I’ve expanded the demo snippet in the hope that it might clarify things further.

Comment: This is very comprehensive, thanks. So if I go with #3, it's the server's backend script's duty to read all duplicate keys and convert them to an array.

Comment: Yes — either based on specific knowledge of the fields it expects or based on a field naming convention. But you can certainly send JSON instead, which has the advantage of being able to represent structured values of types other than "string" or "file". It’s just the `Object.fromEntries(formData)` alone is not always sufficient to perform a mapping in the client.

Comment: Came back again and added more details at the end since I realized it might not be clear what I mean about needing an intermediate mapping.

Comment: I think one can learn a whole lot of other JavaScript stuff from this alone, not just fromEntries and formData. Thanks a lot. This is super useful.